# How to refactor this Redux connect code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, ecmascript-5

I want to use Redux connect and asyncConnect in a stateless component (pure function), so I need to refactor these class decorators into regular function calls.

However, I cannot find an example of asyncConnect with connect anywhere.

**Here's what I have:**

```
@asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({ params, store: { dispatch, getState } }) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadUser(params.userID))
    }
  },
}])
@connect(
  state => ({ // eslint-disable-line
    user: state.publicData.user.data,
    error: state.publicData.user.error,
    loading: state.publicData.user.loading,
  }),
  { initializeWithKey })
export default class UserProfile extends Component {
  ...stuff
}
```

**Here's what I need:**

```
asyncConnect(
  someStuff,
  connect(moreStuff)
)(props => <div />)
```

I just have no idea how to actually write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `compose` function that Dan provides in redux.

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

...

export default compose(
  asyncConnect(...),
  connect(...)
)(props => <div />);
```

`compose` gets applied from right to left.

[Official documentation on `compose`.](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/compose.md)

---

As a matter of interest this is essentially the alternative approach to using the decorator syntax you are using with classes.  You could use the same approach with classes.

---

And a bit of advice/tip.

React leans heavily on functional concepts.  It helped me immensely by getting myself comfortable with some of these.  I *highly* recommend the following free online book.  You need not go all the way down into the world of Monads, I would say at least the first 6 chapters will do you a massive solid going forward.

https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. You are correct in saying this approach is also applicable to classes, I wonder if there is any benefit to decorators besides "nicer" syntax?

Comment: I guess the real "benefit" of decorators is their collocation with the class they are decorating.  Easier to know what additional behaviour the class has.  My only gripe with them is that the feature is still in proposal and is currently subject to an update.  So you put your code base at risk to some admin update work if the proposal does change.

Comment: I don't think compose can be used in this way. Even the most basic example fails with a TypeError: `export default compose( function() { return true } )`

`TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.compose) is not a function`

Comment: My bad! You must import from `redux` not `react-redux`. :)